# Confirmation message - Javascript rails application

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm a bit new to rails and I'm just trying to display a confirmation message when a "Proposition" (created model) has been inserted. For this, I'm using a javascript functionality embedded to rails.
Unfortunately, when I click and submission button, the proposition is correctly inserted but I can't find a way to display this confirmation message (like "proposition correctly submitted" for example)...

Below the code that I'm using :

Proposition Model :

```
class Proposition < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :ad
attr_accessible :email, :name, :phone, :price
validates_presence_of :name or :price or :email or :phone
end
```

Create method in controller :

```
def create
@ad = Ad.find(params[:ad_id])
@proposition = @ad.propositions.create(params[:proposition])

respond_to do |format|
if @proposition.save
format.html { redirect_to ad_path(@ad), notice: 'Proposition was successfully created.' }
format.json { render json: ad_path(@ad), status: :created, location: @proposition }
format.js 
else
format.html { render action: "new" }
format.json { render json: @proposition.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
format.js { render action: "new" }
end
end
end
```

_form.html.erb :

```
<%= form_for [@ad, @ad.propositions.build], :remote => true do |f| %>
<% if @proposition.errors.any? %>
<div id="error_explanation">
<h2><%= pluralize(@proposition.errors.count, "error") %> prohibited this proposition from being saved:</h2>
<ul>
<% @proposition.errors.full_messages.each do |msg| %>
<li><%= msg %></li>
<% end %>
</ul>
</div>
<% end %>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :Prénom %><br />
<%= f.text_field :name %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :"Adresse mail" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :email %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :Téléphone %><br />
<%= f.text_field :phone %>
</div>
<div class="field">
<%= f.label :"Prix proposé" %><br />
<%= f.text_field :price %>
</div>
<div class="actions">
<%= f.submit %>
</div>
<% end %>
```

create.js.erb :

```
$('#new_proposition').fadeOut(1000);
```

new.js.erb :

```
$('#new_proposition_link').hide().after('<%= j render("form") %>');
```

Thanks for your help !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have a `create.js.erb` file, you can use JS to display an alert message or insert a confirmation message into the page like so,

```
# app/views/.../create.js.erb

$('#new_proposition').before('<p>Proposition correctly submitted!</p>');
$('#new_proposition').fadeOut(1000);
```

This inserts the `<p>Proposition correctly submitted!</p>` before the #new_proposition element. You may want to insert it somewhere else since this element will disappear.